# Google Play Store reviews identifier that can be fetched within app

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I need an unique identifier to link the app usage data collected from my app with the reviews posted by the same user on the Play Store. As of now, Google does not expose any unique identifier in the [reviews](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews) which can be obtained within the app so that user's app usage data and their reviews can be linked. Is there anything available to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a gross invasion of the Reviewer's privacy. You should not be doing this.

If you go down this route, especially if you don't tell the user, then it is likely you will break the [Google Play User Data policies](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/) and get your app or your account suspended.

Comment: Few clarifications, how to do you think Google Ads work? How do you think recommendation systems work? I am not asking for user's personal data, I am asking for a correlation id which can tell me what a reviewer is rating in Play Store and to retrieve that id again in the app.Also, I never said I am not going to disclose that information to user.

Comment: Reviews are supposed to be private if the reviewer wants them to be. This is why it is an invasion of privacy.